# Dynamic add Image and data with Ant-Design and ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I can't add an image while executing. When adding an image, the image does not appear, I use a dynamic form with the same inputs when adding a form which will later be stored by looping, but I have problems when adding images. I use a plugin from ant design.

Here's the code.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { Button,Form,Input } from 'antd';
import { 
  PlusOutlined,
  MinusCircleOutlined,
} from '@ant-design/icons';

function Ad_abhb() {
  const [Img1,setImg] = useState([]);

  const i = 0;
  const AddImg4 = (i) =>{
    const [imgPrev1,setImgPrev1] = useState('');   
    const ImgC1=(e)=>{
      const reader = new FileReader();
      const vImg = e.target.files[0];
      setImgPrev1(URL.createObjectURL(vImg));  
      reader.readAsDataURL(vImg);
      reader.onload = () => {[...setImg(reader.result)]}
    }
    return(<>
      <Form.Item  className='imgHobi'>
        <Input id={'uImg4'+i.kd} type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" onChange={ImgC1} hidden />
        <label htmlFor={'uImg4'+i.kd}>
        {imgPrev1.length >= 1 ?<>
          <div className='imgLoad'> 
            <img src={imgPrev1} className='getImg' alt=''/>  
          </div>
        </>:<>
          <div className='imgLoad'> 
            <div className='UpImg'>
              <div className='UpCore'>
                <PlusOutlined style={{fontSize:'20px'}}/>
              </div>
            </div> 
          </div>
        </>}
        </label>
      </Form.Item>
    </>)
  }
  const SimpanA4=()=>{
    console.log(Img1)
  }
  return (<>
      <h1>hobi</h1>
      <div className='konten'>
        <Form >
          <Form.List name='Hobi'>
          {(fields, { add, remove }) => (<>
            {fields.map((field,i)=>{
              return(
              <div key={field.key} className='cardAdminMod hobiList' >                   
                <AddImg4 kd={i}/>
                <Form.Item className='inputHobi' name="Hobi" {...field}>
                  <Input />
                </Form.Item>
                {fields.length > 1 ? <div className='rmHobi'><MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => remove(field.name)} /></div>: null}
              </div>)
            })}
            <Form.Item className='addPlusHobi'>
              <Button type="dashed" onClick={() => add()} block icon={<PlusOutlined />}>
                Add Data
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </>)}
          </Form.List>
        </Form>
      </div>
    <div className="titleAdmin butSide">  
      <Button onClick={SimpanA4}>Save</Button>   
    </div>
  </>)
}

export default Ad_abhb;
```

So, can anyone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.